# Flash Message - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Rails application I have flash messages and I would like it so that each time there is a flash message, it scrolls down from the top (all the content goes lower) stays for a few seconds and the slides back up.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Do I toggle the height?

#### Update

Sometimes the message will be injected into the HTML which means that the `slideDown` won't work since the DOM has already loaded, how can I have it so jQuery looks for `.message` and then applies the `slideDown` and `slideUp`?

Comment: What are `flash messages`?

Comment: look at `slideUp,slideDown` or `slideToggle` in jQuery API  http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Clarify your question and what you have tried so far, post if you have any non-working code sample ?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Flash messages are just notices that appear and disappear after a few seconds.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I haven't tried anything as I don't know how to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to display flash notices in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005381/best-way-to-display-flash-notices-in-rails)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make it slide down, wait for couple of seconds and slide back again with this:

```
$(selector for your message).slideDown(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(selector for your message).slideUp();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Change the `5000` to the time you want the message to stay visible in milliseconds.

And remember to set `display: none;` in CSS for your message, so that it does not appear until jQuery goes in.

Comment: How can I do it so it slides up when there is a message inside?

Comment: I guess you would have to check this on server-side and add appropriate class or `data` argument so the jQuery would know whether it should animate or not. Or check with jQuery if it's empty...

Comment: How can I check if it's empty with jQuery?

Comment: `if (!$(your message).html()) { is empty }`

Comment: Ah, ok. Also, see the update I made. It might be why it's not working

Comment: It is good that DOM has already loaded. Just set `display: none` in CSS for your message. It will be hidden until jQuery shows it with `slideDown`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that I use Ajax so when the user hits the save button, it injects a div with the class message into the header so slideDown isn't working

Comment: It should work. How do you inject the div into the DOM? For example this should work: `$(".header").append(message).slideDown();`.

Comment: Some messages are injected using erb tags and the one where I save with Ajax, I have a update.js.erb file that contains `$('.header').append('<div class="message" id="green">Saved</div>');`

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RPSwV/. Dynamically appending content to page does not prevent animations from working correctly.

Comment: Just click the run button again - the animation begins the moment you load the page.

Comment: I have no idea how else to help you. It ought to work. Sorry.

Comment: It's not your fault. For some reason the append is not actually injecting the code

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your flash message is contained in some element that is (or can be) identified by class.  You want to find the first one, then adjust the scroll position to the top of that element (or some offset from it), then wait and scroll back to the top.

```
$(function() {
    var $flashMsg = $('.flash-message:first');
    if ($flashMsg.length) { // we've got one
       var top = $flashMsg.offset().top;
       $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: top })
                     .delay(3000)
                     .animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do I enter the class name?

Comment: That would be in the HTML surrounding your flash message.  Been awhile since I've done any Ruby, but something like `<div class="flash-message">@flash[:error]</div>`

Comment: I may have misunderstood your actual requirements.  This will scroll the window to the error message, not slide open an error message at the top.  That's actually much easier.

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery's `slideDown()` and call `slideUp()` in the callback coupled with a timer:

```
$("#message").slideDown(500, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
$("#message").slideUp(500);  
},5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function flashRed(sel, blinks){  //using jQuery
    blinks = blinks||3
    var x = $(sel),
        bg = x.css('background-color'),
        fg = x.css('color'),
        counter = 0,
        f, b;

    for(var i = 0; i < blinks * 2; i++){  

       setTimeout(function(){
           if(counter%2){
             f=fg; b=bg
           }
           else{
             f='white'; b='red'
           }
           counter++

           x.css({'color':f, 'background-color':b})
       },i*400)
    } 

 }
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary to your answer, in order for everyone else to know how you solved the problem?

Comment: This solution allows as many flashes as you want.  Call it like this:

Comment: Call it like this:  flashRed('slector', 4).  This will cause the text of the selector to flash 4 times.

Comment: The trick is to use a counter to alternate colors.  You cannot use the index in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
here duration is in milliseconds.

```
$.fn.flash_msg=function(duration){
  this.fadeIn().delay(duration).fadeOut(function(){
    this.remove();
  })
}

$("#message").flash_msg(1500);
```