# How to alert inline of button

Tags: javascript

I know already how to alert by use javascript or Jquery. But just onclick button I apply javascript external or internal. What I need is we alert inline of button 
Example:

```
<button name="my_btn" id="my_btn" onClick="alert('Hello I am alert')">Alert</button>
```

If it is possible please tell me. I am waiting for all of you

Comment: Looks like you already have a working solution, what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I never really understand why someone wants to do it this way, but here is an inline alert on a button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello World')">Show Alert</button>
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfQPT/)

[By the way, I believe this question has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607847/how-does-inline-javascript-in-html-work)

Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thank it is work but before I try it still not work I don't know too but for now I use this it work thank. Oh maybe the browser is catching

Comment: Are you sure your browser has Javascript enabled? And are you sure that you don't have any other JS or jQuery functions intercepting this click? Maybe you need to post more code?

Comment: call like this <input type='button' onclick="javascript:alert('test');" value='Button'/> it should work in all browsers

Comment: @BongYuth I guess your `button` is within a `form`. By default many browsers submit the form (which reloads the page) when clicking a `button` without `type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='button' onclick="javascript:alert('test');" value='Button'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<input type='button' onclick="alert('a');" value='Button'/>
```

Comment: Thank it is work but before I try it still not work I don't know too but for now I use this it work thank. Oh maybe the browser is catching

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to call the `alert` function from your HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click me!" onclick="alert('your message here');" />
```

But it is generally accepted you should not inline JavaScript and not use alert.
You can check this question for more: [Flash Message - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006477/flash-message-jquery)